# Codeigniter - Submit Upload file when Onchange

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have an upload form. When a file is uploaded I want it to be automatically submitted to my controller. But for some reason, I can't upload the file with my code.

I create my view with html parameter on JS File

Here is my **View/Form**

```
 html += '<?php echo form_open_multipart(\''+ base_url + 'daftar_izin/upload/' + id + '\');?> <input type="file" name="laporan" onchange="form.submit()" /></form>' ;
```

**Controller (daftar_izin)** :

```
public function upload($id_izin) {
    $this->m_di->updateDoc($id_izin);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_alert', 'Laporan berhasil diupload');
    redirect( base_url('daftar_izin') );
}
```

**Model** :

```
public function updateDoc($id_izin) {
    $d_t_d = array(
        'laporan' => $this->uploadDoc()
    );
    $this->db->where( 'id_izin', $id_izin )->update('tb_izin', $d_t_d);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_alert', 'Data izin berhasil diubah');
}

public function uploadDoc()
{
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'docx';
    $config['file_name']            = $this->id_izin;
    $config['overwrite']            = true;
    $config['max_size']             = 100000000; // 1MB
    // $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    // $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
       if ($this->upload->do_upload('laporan')) 
       {
        return $this->upload->data("file_name");
    }
     return "default.docx";
 }
```

Method model `uploadDoc()` always returns "default.docx" , so `$this->upload->do_upload('laporan')` never works.

Comment: just use upload error to find the problem

Comment: @DevsiOdedra it doesnt return anything

Comment: Check your logs

Answer (score 0):

uploadDoc function use in controller daftar_izin, $this->upload->do_upload('laporan') not found in model